# Can anyone identify this integrated circuit? I've tried to look it up but haven't come up with anything yet

Tags: integrated-circuit

Here are a couple of different pictures of it. It is an 8 pin IC. It appears to have the following letters on it:

```
PTK02A
RBSLR2000
2051AASAR
```

To give a little more context this is from off of a pretty simple device that is used to heat tea or coffee. It has a single button with an LED that alternates between off and 3 different colors representing 3 different temperature settings. There are maybe 15 total components on the pcb board where this came from. The device is similar to something like this one https://a.co/d/9KsVaTu. Let me know if there are any additional questions I can answer. I am mostly interested in knowing if there is a way for me to dump the memory on it and then figure out its program if possible. I know the program is probably going to be pretty simple for such a simple device but I thought it would be an interesting experiment to see if I could figure out how it worked. Thank you in advance for any information.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very peculiar to put the print underneath the component. Makes me think they don't want anyone to read it, so perhaps a custom IC.

Comment: @Lundin I got a sample from ${major US-american chip vendor} where they somehow mounted the packaging upside down, so that the pins didn't end on board level (and then rudely refused to send me working samples, although I didn't even ask for that but just said I wanted to point out a critical QA blunder to someone who might be able to trace that lot). This might be factory rejects that got sold at a steep discount or by a moonlight operation, where being fed through the marking machine upside down was the reason for rejection. Or they are just especially bad moonlights/counterfeits.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sounds like you have been in touch with TI customer support...

Comment: @Lundin I'm *baffled*! Totally *blown away*! How could you **possibly** tell?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It would have been my first guess even if you hadn't said US-American :) They are the market leader in bad support.