# Can anyone identify what this is inside this IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit

So I attempted to decap an IC using the approach shown here https://youtu.be/SWX-s-Obkc0 using a hot air rework station. That seemed to work but what I found inside doesn't resemble a circuit of any kind I've seen and so I was wondering if someone here could explain to me what I am looking at. The chip I decapped was the one shown in this previous question I asked about here in case you want to see what it looked like before I decapped it: [Can anyone identify this integrated circuit? I've tried to look it up but haven't come up with anything yet](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/666391/can-anyone-identify-this-integrated-circuit-ive-tried-to-look-it-up-but-haven)

Here is what I found inside after decapping it plus here are some photos of the major pieces as well. I expected to find something like is shows in the video I linked to, but instead it looks like I just have strange pieces of plain metal so I'm a little confused. Thanks in advance for any enlightenment you can provide.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it looks like you succeeded in fracturing the IC, not in decapping it

Comment: The pictures are too blurry to discern any details. Set your camera in a macro mode.

Comment: The interesting side of the semiconductor crystal is still covered with plastic. You can see only the substrat on the 3rd picture. But, even if you remove this plastic with some strong acid, do you really expect to recognize the function of the structures?